# Visual Studio Code cannot detect my tests

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, pytest

Visual Studio Code cannot discover my test files despite the fact that I can run them in CMD.

settings.json:

```
{
    "git.autofetch": true,
    "git.confirmSync": false,
    "git.enableSmartCommit": true,
    "python.pythonPath": "C:/Users/CEM/Anaconda3/python.exe",
    "python.dataScience.sendSelectionToInteractiveWindow": true,
    "explorer.confirmDelete": false,
    "explorer.confirmDragAndDrop": false,
    "python.testing.pyTestEnabled": true,
    "python.testing.pyTestPath": "C:\\Users\\CEM\\Anaconda3\\Scripts\\pytest.exe",
    "pythonTestExplorer.testFramework": "pytest",
    "python.testing.cwd": ""
}
```

Visual Studio Code version:

```
Version: 1.34.0 (user setup)
Commit: a622c65b2c713c890fcf4fbf07cf34049d5fe758
Date: 2019-05-15T21:59:37.030Z
Electron: 3.1.8
Chrome: 66.0.3359.181
Node.js: 10.2.0
V8: 6.6.346.32
OS: Windows_NT x64 10.0.17134
```

Python 3.6.8 64-bit as part of Anaconda installation

Structure of files:

```
> main folder
>> subfolder
>>> script.py
>>> __init__.py
>> test_folder
>>> __TEST__
>>>> (here are testing data files, .csv etc.)
>>> test.py
>>> __init__.py
```

Function code:

```
import pytest
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

from subfolder.script import func

class Test:
    def test_zero_variance_filter(self):
        assert 2 == 2
```

When I am running in cmd:
`...test folder directory...>pytest -q test.py`

the test is normally run and I see the output whether it is successful or not.

I played with settings (i.e. changing python environment, setting a temporary test environment), tried different folder locations, restarted VSC, was checking if all extensions are there, none of it worked. Any suggestions?